# Should I use SQLite database version 2.1 or 3.0?

Tags: php, sqlite

I am new to Sqlite and am starting to play around with using it for a small php project.  My question is should I use an sqlite 2.1 DB or sqlite 3?  What are the pros and cons of each?  Is sqlite 3 available on most hosts nowadays? I want to use the version that is most widely available.

Any insight would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite 3 adds UTF-8 support, so for that reason alone you're far better off with it than an older version.  unless you have a specific reason to require backwards compatibility with older versions you should use version 3.

SQLite 3 also supports BLOBs and offers improved concurrency.

Comment: Sounds good, is SQLite 3 available on most hosts with php 5.x? installed?

Comment: I couldn't give you any statistics on that, sorry.  However, I'd imagine most PHP5 would have it, as the version 3 codebase has been around since 2004

Comment: I found some info that says SQLite 3 is only available on php 5.3.x and SQLite 2.1 support is removed in PHP 5.4. That makes it tough to offer wide compatibility with PHP 5.x servers.

Answer (score 2):

The first production release of SQLite 3 shipped in 2004. There have been more than 20 (a lot more, I got bored counting) releases since then, and it's now at 3.7.9 as of 01-Nov-2011.

The last V2 release appears to have been in 2005. That was 2.8.17. V2.1 was last updated in 2001.

See [SQLite Release History](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html)

If there are hosts out there that don't offer V3, I'd avoid them.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I would avoid them too, but I can't control what some users of the script will be using as a host...